# Install Linux with Desktop Environment via jClouds/Apache Brooklyn

Tags: jclouds, brooklyn

I want to install a Linux machine (preferably Red Hat) with a Desktop Environment (lets say Xcfe, but it could be another one) via Brooklyn (with jClouds).

In the same way that in Apache Brooklyn there is a VanillaWindowsProcess which installs a Windows machine which it is accessible via Remote Desktop, I want to do it something similar (with VanillaSoftwareProcess) but for Linux.

Is there something to add to the Blueprint or should I do it programmatically? I mean, execute a blueprint with a wrapper of the VanillaSoftwareProcess which after the installation, launches the commands to install the desktop.environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no blueprint which does that yet.

But as you said, you can achieve this by using a [VanillaSoftwareProcess](https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/learnmore/catalog/catalog-item.html#!entities/brooklyn.entity.basic.VanillaSoftwareProcess) entity, like so:

```
name: RHEL with desktop GUI
location: 
  jclouds:aws-ec2:
    region: <your-region>
    identity: <your-identity>
    credential: <your-credential>
    osFamily: RHEL
services:
- type: org.apache.brooklyn.entity.software.base.VanillaSoftwareProcess
  install.command: |

    # Command to install you desktop GUI here...

  launch.command: |

    # Command to launch your desktop GUI here...
```